# Python simplejson quoting for R rjson input

Tags: python, r, simplejson, rjson

I'm processing data within Python, and would like to stream records to R using JSON formatting and `simplejson` on the Python side, and `rjson` on the `R` side.

How can I output records out of Python so that R's `fromJSON` can process them into a one-line dataframe? Thanks

```
 try:
     import simplejson as json
 except ImportError:
     import json

 record = {'x':1,'y':1}
 print json.dumps( record )
```

Result:

```
 {"y": 1, "x": 1}
```

However, I'd need the result to be `"{\"x\":1,\"y\":2}"`, as `R` needs that formatting to use the data:

```
 library(rjson)
 as.data.frame( fromJSON( "{\"x\":1,\"y\":2}" ) )
   x y
 1 1 2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

> (1) If your JSON does **not** contain both single & double quotes, wrap the entire JSON in the quote type not being used.
>
> (2) If you need to escape the quotes (ie, because both are in your JSON), then you need to escape the escape character.  That is, use double slashes:  `\\"y\\"`

(note that the second point applies to any string in R that has needs an escape character)